# How can I get a rootline / breadcrumb within an Extbase Frontent Plugin in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

Is there a way to work with dataProcessing / MenuProcessor within an Extbase Frontend Plugin in TYPO3 9?

I want to build a page rootline within a plugin. I know how to make it in page context or in a tt-content element but can I get it in a plugin too?

I tried the following in my plugin setup, but this does not work:

```
plugin.tx_extensions_show {
    view {
        ...
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            10 {
                special = rootline
                special.range = 1|-1
                includeNotInMenu = 1
                as = rootline
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your plugin code you can fetch the rootline in an array:

```
// ($MP and $this->context are optional)
$rootline = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(RootlineUtility::class, $uid, $MP, $this->context);
$rootlinePages = $rootline->get();
```

Now you can pass $rootlinePages on to your FLUID template.

Hth.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60497300/6065453) of [Loek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5511057/loek) to do it in the controller an not in the fluid template I found my own solution to fetch the rootline in an array and pass it to my Fluid template for TYPO3 9:

```
    $rootLineUtility = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\RootlineUtility($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);
    $rootline = $rootLineUtility->get();
    $this->view->assign('rootline', $rootline);
```